# Multiple form validation in one page MVC 4 with fluent validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, fluentvalidation

I have a problem like this,In my page I have two forms and each form tag represent different action in controller.what I want to do is I want to have separate validation for each forms.

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" action="@Url.Action("Index")" method="POST">

          <div class="row">
            <div class="span5">
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label">From</label>
                    <div class="controls">

                        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.FromDate, "Date")

                        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label">To</label>
                    <div class="controls">

                        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ToDate, "Date")

                        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="span5">
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" >Employee Group</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.EmployeeGroupId, Model.EmployeeGroupList, "-- Select Employee Group --")
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="Description">Employee(s) <span class="required"></span></label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedEmployeeList, Model.EmployeeList , new
                            {
                                @Id = "EmployeeInfo",

                                @class = "chzn-select",
                                data_placeholder = "Choose  Employee(s) ...",
                                style = "width:350px;"
                            })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
        <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit"><i class="icon-ok"></i>Filter</button>
        &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
        <button class="btn" type="reset"><i class="icon-undo"></i>Reset</button>
    </div>
    </form>

    <form  id="form-attendance-edit-list" class="form-horizontal" action="@Url.Action("UpdateAll")" method="POST">

        @if (!ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            <div class="alert alert-error">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><i class="icon-remove"></i></button>
                <strong><i class="icon-remove"></i>Oh Cemex!</strong>
                <br>
                @Html.ValidationSummary()
            </div>
        }
     @Html.Partial("List", Model)
    </form>
```

I want to validate each form in a page separately.currently it validate both forms at once.how I can achieve this ?

Comment: I can see in your code just one form, the other one is only for ValidationErrors

Comment: here I delete some of the code to make it smaller.let me add that.it has a partial view.actually I want to validate that partial list separately and other form data separately.